# ¿Como utilizar el LIKE con un DATE_FORMAT?

Tags: mysql, select, base-de-datos

Tengo una consulta en la que necesito hacer un `LIKE` en el `WHERE` indicando la fecha actual.

Es esta:

```
SELECT orden FROM tareas WHERE tipo = "Dos" 
AND (fechaCierre IS NULL OR fechaCierre LIKE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Claro, eso de `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')` me devuelve "2018-10-19", pero quiero que el WHERE se comporte como `LIKE '2018-10-19%'`, pero no se como ponerle el % al LIKE de la consulta.

No se si me explico. Quiero poner el % en el LIKE despues de la "operacion" de DATE_FORMAT, pero no me funciona.

He probado a poner `LIKE (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'))%` `LIKE [DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')]%` `LIKE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') + %` y nada, no hay forma de que funcione.

Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo que entonces tu campo `fechaCierre` es del tipo `yyyy-mm-dd%` y es de tipo String?

Comment: Prueba CONCAT: `LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'),'%')`

Comment: Si lo que quieres es todas las fechas que corresponden a un dia, independientemente de la hora, eso ya lo obtienes con DATE_FORMAT al comparar solo los datos de año-mes-día, no tiene sentido el uso de LIKE.

Comment: @Carmen eso le había comentado yo. Pero tras releer, me temo que es que tiene un campo con una cadena de texto que comienza con la fecha (si no no le veo sentido a la pregunta)

Comment: @Pikoh supongo que puede ser el caso, que nos diga M.Giner.

Comment: Efectivamente, así era como bien dice @Pikoh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para concatenar campos o cadenas en **MySQL**:

1.- Usando la función **`CONCAT(campo1, campo2, ...)`**. El valor devuelto es el string concatenado de todos los parámetros.

```
LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'), '%')
```

2.- Usando el operador **`||`** de la siguiente forma: `campo1 || campo2`. Para que esto funcione es necesario establecer la variable `sql_mode` al valor `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`:

```
SET sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT;

...
LIKE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') || '%'
...
```